# How to search and tag location without enabling gps?

Tags: android

I'm just trying to create an app where user can post events like birthday. When creating the event, user is required to fill the location of the event. Is there a way where i can search and select location without enabling the gps? It is just a simple typing the name of location in a textbox and a list of suggestions will pop out and user need to pick one. It doesn't have to be accurate. I've seen people using place picker but I'm not sure if that is what i want. Is there better option to do this? Any help and recommendations are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can just refer to this topic on StackOverflow again. [Getting user location while offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46906017/getting-location-offline)

Comment: I'm thinking more like let's say for example i can tag either tokyo, washington, or kuala lumpur instead of latitude and longitude